# Is it safe to store user information in Localstorage?

Tags: local-storage

I built an app with authentication, and upon navigation to private route, I'm checking in the redux store if user object exist. when reloading the page, obviously the store clears. I thought of persist-state solution with redux-storage , but I see that the data is being stored in the LocalStorage.
is it safe that all data is being shown there? information like user id, name, email, etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not store plaintext values (user name, id, password etc.) in localstorage. Assume the following:

1. Someone with access to the physical machine: he can either grab the Chrome profile files, containing my localstorage, or he can open Dev Tools in my browser and see stuff he shouldn't.
2. A malicious browser (or app with a browser control) can gain access, by getting you to browse to the site and copying the values.
3. Never rely in your app on info you got back from localstorage. Assume someone manipulated it. Crass, imaginary example: if you store my cart total in localstorage, to save time on recalculating it later, assume I changed it to a lower number on the client.

Finally, assume some of your users will use a private tab to browse to your site, at which point you wont be able to utilize localstorage. So why not design to work without it?